# Bluemix: How I can configure a delivery pipeline stage build to tag git?

Tags: git, ibm-cloud, pipeline, devops

I have a Build & Deploy Pipeline in Bluemix, I would like to tag git if the stage has been successfully deployed.
Currently, I had added a build step after a deploy step into my deploy stage with a shell script that look like:

```
# put the git tag
echo 'Put tag build_$BUILD_NUMBER on git'
git tag build_$BUILD_NUMBER
git push --tags
```

The returned error is:

> fatal: could not read Username for 'https://hub.jazz.net': No such device or address
>   Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure

But it seems that I have no .gitcredentials file to push without need to add authentication information.

How can I push a tag on git into my delivery pipeline??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enter in the username and password for the remote url. I have tested the following in the past and it worked for me:

```
 git remote set-url origin https://$USERNAME:$PASSWORD@hub.jazz.net/git/user/project
```

where USERNAME and PASSWORD are environment properties on the stage. I recommend setting the password as a secure property so the value is not displayed in the logs.  You should be able to push your tags after that.

Comment: I'm not really enthousiast to add login and password into the delivery pipeline. However, if this is the only way, I will restrict the pipeline administration to only me to evict my password propagation..

Comment: if you set the password as a secure property.  The value will be hidden (appear as ****) in the logs as well as the environment properties tab when someone looks there

Comment: Thanks a lot @crjenkins89 for the answer and Cotonea for the question this has done me well whilst looking to achieve the same. Just an FYI for anyone inexperienced in Bash like myself and face an issue with the "@" in their email username ruining this remote command, '%40' works as a substitute. I.e. my username property looks something like scott.allen%40domain.com.